Git pull stuck and doesn't work in WebStorm
Recently I had a problem with WebStorm and git. I see blue arrow which indicates that I can update the branch, but I actually cannot update it.

I also tried git pull manually, but it stuck(any branch). Any idea how to fix that and what is the reason?

Reloading my computer didn't help. Checkout does work. Pushing works if no merge is needed.
I also tried rm -f .git/index.lock. And this one:
git fsck && git gc --prune=now

which leads to many errors like this one:

It worked after reloading the IDE, helped once, and stuck again.

Git for windows 2.47?

git version 2.47.0.windows.1

Try with 2.46.... I've read around here of issues with 2.47.

v2.47.0 is buggy. Downgrade to v2.46, upgrade to 2.47.0.20241025 or 2.47.0.windows.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%202.47&searchOn=3

Upgrading to git version 2.47.0.windows.2 helped!!! Thanks a lot. I hope it will not break again but it seems to work just fine up until now.

Thanks to the guys in the comments! Upgrading to git version 2.47.0.windows.2 helped!!!
